# how to delete the data of a stock in a given period in dolphindb?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

how to delete the data of a stock in a given period in dolphindb?

I create a database and a table in dolphindb:

```
login("admin", "123456")

n=1000000
ID=rand(`a1`a2`a3`a4`a5`a6`a7`a8`b1`b2`b3`c1`c2`c3, n)
dates=2017.08.07..2017.08.11
date=rand(dates, n)
x=rand(10.0, n)
t=table(ID, date, x)

if(existsDatabase("dfs://compodb")){
    dropDatabase("dfs://compodb")
}

dbDate = database(, VALUE, 2017.08.07..2017.08.11)
dbID = database(, HASH,  [STRING, 5]);
db = database("dfs://compodb", COMPO, [dbDate, dbID])
pt = db.createPartitionedTable(t, "pt", `date`ID)
```

I want to delete the data of ID=`c2 during the time from 2017.08.07 to 2017.08.11. Is there an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You can first define a function to delete a certain stock on a certain day, and then use the loop or ploop function to delete the data in the specified time period:

```py
def dropCodeData(dbName, tableName, code,day){
    cnt = exec count(*) from loadTable(dbName, tableName) where date=day, ID=code
    if(cnt==0) return;
    hashNumber = hashBucket(code, 5)
    t = select * from loadTable(dbName, tableName) where date=day, hashBucket(ID, 5)=hashNumber
    delete from t where ID = code
    dropPartition(dbName,"/"+temporalFormat(day,"yyyyMMdd")+"/Key"+string(hashNumber))
    loadTable(dbName, tableName).append!(t)
}

ploop(dropCodeData{database("dfs://compodb"), "pt", `c2}, 2017.08.07..2017.08.11)

loop(dropCodeData{database("dfs://compodb"), "pt", `c2}, 2017.08.07..2017.08.11)

//delete certain stock o certain day
dropCodeData(database("dfs://compodb"), "pt", `c2, 2017.08.10)
```